# Laravel fill returns null

Tags: php, database, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to update a product in laravel, but it does not work properly,

my Controller's update method looks like this:

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request)
{
    # Get input values
    $data = $request->all();
    $productID = $data['id'];
    $product = Product::find($productID);

    $product->fill($data);
    # Validate  input
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Product::$rules);

    if ($product->save())
    {
        # save language selection
        $lsCounter = 0;
        $langSelecName = $request->input('language');
        $langSelecFile = $request->file('language');

        if ($langSelecName)
        {
            $projectPath = $dProjectPath . "languages";

            foreach ($langSelecName as $langSelecNameKey => $langSelecNameValue)
            {
                if ($langSelecFile[$lsCounter]['input_vid_lang'] != null)
                {
                    $langVidFileName = $langSelecFile[$lsCounter]['input_vid_lang']->getClientOriginalName();

                    $languages = new Language();
                    $languages['short_name'] = $langSelecNameValue;
                    $languages['input_video'] = $projectLangPath . '\\' . $langVidFileName;

                    $languages->product()->associate($product);

                    $langData = [
                        'languagesShortName' => $languages['short_name'],
                        'languagesInputVideo' => $languages['input_video']
                    ];

                    $intProductID = intval($productID);
                    $findLangId = $languages->find($intProductID);

                    $findLangId->fill($langData);

                    if ($languages->save())
                    {
                        $langSelecFile[$lsCounter]['input_vid_lang']->move($projectLangPath, $langVidFileName);
                    }
                }

                $lsCounter++;
            }
        }

    } else {
        return redirect()->route('editProduct', $productID)->with('message', 'Error')->withInput();
    }
```

I get the following error after I try to update it, the error looks like this:

> Call to a member function fill() on null

And it points to this line:

```
$findLangId->fill($langData);
```

I appreciate some help, thank you.

**Edit**

Ok people said that `$intProductRomID` is null, but I get the correct product id if I dd($intProductRomID).

Comment: It's pretty certain that $findLangId is null because the line about it returned no results.

Comment: @Josh Rumbut but if I return $languages and $intProductRomID I get some result, could you show me of how you would solve this

Comment: The title is incorrect ! You are trying to call `fill()` on `Null` like so `null->fill()`

Comment: @zorx my bad edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, the following line is return `null`:

```
$findLangId = $languages->find($intProductRomID);
```

Meaning this won't be valid:

```
$findLangId->fill($langData);
```

In other words, if you were to var_dump out `$languages->all()`, you will not find `$intProductRomID` in there. If you are unsure, swap out `->find` with `->findOrFail()` (which, considering you aren't doing any error catching or checking, you probably should be using it instead).

**Edit**

After some conversation in the comments, it has been established that the wrong field was being used for reference. Use a `where` instead:

```
$languages->where('product_rom_id', $intProductRomID);
```

Comment: but why does he not find it?

Comment: Most likely because its not there, but impossible to tell without seeing the data. Print out $intProductRomID to make sure its right

Comment: I just saw your edit - that $intProductRomID is null. That would be why...

Comment: no it is not null if I dd($intProductRomID) I get the current id

Comment: Ok is the current id 100% in the data set? Are you using default keys "id" for your database? Can you dump your data with $languages->all()

Comment: I tried putting a simple int into the find like this `->find(49)` but I still get this error `Call to a member function fill() on null`

Comment: Is 49 def in there? Can you dump the data with ->all()

Comment: the current id is 100%, ill edit the question and show you the ouput of $languages->all()

Comment: 49 isn't there. By default, find will use the "id" field (not your custom field)

Comment: 49 is there I just maximized the first two fields

Comment: It isn't. You have `"id" => 1, "product_rom_id" => 46` twice. More importantly, reread my last comment - it won't use "product_rom_id" with find unless you have specififeid a custom key. It's look for 49 within "id"

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php

Comment: ahh I get it sorry :)

Comment: so I have to look for my product_rom_id

Comment: thanks, so this where method is equal to a find right?

Comment: I don't understand the question. But please consult the laravel docs on eloquent to get a grasp of what methods are avilable

Comment: ok I did it so far but this just adds data and does not change the current ones

Comment: where will find the record you need. then you do your fill. fetch and update. i feel like i have more than sufficiently answered your original question. if you have further questions, please feel free to post new questions under the php/laravel tag

Comment: Then I will not bother you anymore, sorry and thanks :)